# Edits to the name of enum types are not reflected in the VS2015 *.settings file C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Here is an example enum I have in `EncLib` namespace:

```
public enum Channel { X = 0, Y }
```

In the same solution, I have another namespace `StmLib` references `EncLib` and has a variable of type `Channel` in the EncSettings.settings.

An example file structure is shown below:

[image: Example file structure]

Now, if I rename the enum to `EncoderChannel`:

```
public enum EncoderChannel { X = 0, Y }
```

The change is not reflected in EncSettings.settings. On the left of the picture showing below is `EncLib` in the object browser.
On the right is the dialog box opened from the `EncSettings.settings` by clicking `type dropdown menu` -> `Browse...` -> `EncLib`:
[image: Change is not reflected in EncSettings.settings]

I have tried Rebuild and Clean->Build, the result is the same.

I am also well aware that I can open the `EncSettings.Designer.cs` file and change `Channel` to `EncoderChannel`, but this makes no change to the settings file. This means every time I save the `EncSettings.settings`, I will have to make this edit, because saving will update the designer file to match whatever is shown in the settings file.

Any suggestions and help is appreciated.

---

**Edit:**
Uploaded A side-by-side view of the `EncLib` in object browser and settings page.

As you can see, in the settings page, the variable named `EncoderChannel` has the type `Channel` rather than the expected `EncoderChannel`.
[image: A side-by-side view of the object browser and settings file]

---

**Update 1:**
I have tried removing the `EncLib` reference and re-reference it. This does not solve the problem.

---

**Update 2:**
I have successfully crashed VS2015 and this seems to give me a hint that this is a bug rather than I'm missing some steps here. Procedures to crash VS2015:

1. In `EncSettings.Designer.cs`, change `Channel` to `EncoderChannel`.
2. Re-build.
3. Close VS2015 and restart VS2015.
4. In `EncSettings.settings.cs`, click the `type dropdown menu`, select `Browse`.
5. Click `EncLib` and VS2015 crashes.

I think this means VS2015 has updated `Channel` to `EncoderChannel`, but for some reason, VS2015 crashes when trying to present the update.

---

**Update3:**
I've tried many ways to fix the crash, but I couldn't succeed. I had to roll back to a previous commit from source control. AVOID following the steps mentioned in Update 2.

Comment: What does your encsettings.settings file look like? I'd have expected whatever is in settings to be the name of the setting, not the type but I've not used settings files like that myself so don't know for sure...

Comment: @Chris I have uploaded a picture of the encsettings.settings page.

Comment: When you make a breaking change in the Setting types then it is pretty important to bump up your project's AssemblyVersion so it cannot accidentally use a stale user.config file.  Or you can delete the old file if you can find it back in appdata.

Comment: @HansPassant Is this to avoid the crash or update the setting types? I tried to bump up my assembly version but didn't see updates on types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries, I found myself a simple solution:

1. Close solution.
2. Go to the project directory.
3. Open `EncSettings.settings` with a text editor.
4. Change the following line:

   ```
   <Setting Name="EncoderChannel" Type="EncLib.Channel" Scope="User">
   <Value Profile="(Default)">Y</Value>
   ```

   To

   ```
   <Setting Name="EncoderChannel" Type="EncLib.EncoderChannel" Scope="User">
   <Value Profile="(Default)">Y</Value>
   ```
5. Open `EncSettings.Designer.cs` with a text editor.
6. Change the following line:

   ```
   public global::EncLib.Channel EncoderChannel {
       get {
           return ((global::EncLib.Channel)(this["EncoderChannel"]));
       }
       set {
           this["EncoderChannel"] = value;
       }
   }
   ```

   To

   ```
   public global::EncLib.EncoderChannel EncoderChannel {
       get {
           return ((global::EncLib.EncoderChannel)(this["EncoderChannel"]));
       }
       set {
           this["EncoderChannel"] = value;
       }
   }
   ```
7. Open app.config with a text editor and check if the line below exits:

   ```
   <setting name="EncoderChannel" serializeAs="String">
       <value>Y</value>
   </setting>
   ```

Done!

---

**Update:**

I just found neater solution:

1. In `EncSettings.settings`, change the type of the variable to something else, `string` for example.
2. Rebuild and ignore all errors.
3. Close solution.
4. Re-open solution.
5. Now `EncoderChannel` is shown instead of `Channel` in settings. Change `string` to `EncoderChannel`.

Done!